# Click event for dynamically created link buttons not firing?

Tags: c#

This is application i am doing in c# web application
  I am creating link buttons dynamically as below.

```
for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {         
                LinkButton ln = new LinkButton();
                ln.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString();
                ln.ID =  ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[1].ToString();  
                divonlne.Controls.Add(ln);
                divonlne.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>"));
            }
```

my click event is as follows

```
 ln.Click += new EventHandler(Clicked);
```

In my click event i am getting the linkbutton text and Id as follows

```
   protected void Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LinkButton lno = sender as LinkButton;
            Session["Toname"] = lno.Text;
            Session["idto"] = lno.ID;
        }
```

But this is firing only when the last link button is clicked.
Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already wrote how you subscribe the `Click` Event, but in your sample i cant see it.
Maybe you subscribe on the wrong place. This works...

```
for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{         
    LinkButton ln = new LinkButton();
    ln.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString();
    ln.ID =  ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[1].ToString();  
    ln.Click += new EventHandler(Clicked);
    divonlne.Controls.Add(ln);
    divonlne.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>"));
}
```

Answer (score -2):

When using dynamic controls in a custom control, remember to decorate your class with the **INamingContainer** interface. This ensures recreated controls fit correctly into the hierarchy and remember which events they are supposed to handle.

Comment: This answer should be a comment, and has nothing to do with the question.